# AlbumTableGateway in Zend Framework 2 User Guide

Tags: zend-framework2, tablegateway

In the chapter "[Database and models](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html)" of the current (2.1) ZF2 User Guide there a code snippet, I don't understand:

(block "Using ServiceManager to configure the table gateway and inject into the AlbumTable")

```
...
class Module
{
    // getAutoloaderConfig() and getConfig() methods here

    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                    $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

The variable `$sm` will be later an instance of the `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager`, right? The method Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager#get(...) expects a classname as first argument. But there is no class AlbumTableGateway. There are only two model classes: Album\Model\Album and Album\Model\AlbumTable.

Is it an error in the guide or am I understanding the code wrongly?

Thanks

Comment: Oh, I see now... No class `AlbumTableGateway` is needed, since the calls of `AlbumTableGateway` end in the AlbumTableGateway-Factory, that crates appropriate objects on-the-fly. OK, resolved. :)

Comment: Exactly, the `$sm->get('alias')` requires a class instance that will be returned from the SM by the given alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to think of this is that ServiceManager's `get()` method takes a key value, not a class name. The key value needs to map to something that will result in a class instance being returned.

If the key is within the `invokables` section, then the ServiceManager will try to instantiate the string that the key points to on the assumption that it's a classname:

```
'invokables' => array(
    'some_name' => 'My\Mapper\SomeClassName',
),
```

If the key is within the `factories` section, then the ServiceManager will execute the callback that the key points to and expect an object instance to be returned:

```
'factories' => array(
    'some_name' => function($sm) { return new \My\Mapper\SomeClassName(); },
),
```

In general, you use a factory when you need to do something more than just instantiate a class - usually you need to set up the class with another dependency. If you just need to instantiate a class, use an invokable.